# Facebook application type

Tags: facebook, mobile, canvas, web

We are planning to implement Facebook application to enable easier access to one of our service.

Our key requirements are
    - Support on desktop and mobile platforms.
    - Register/Login using Facebook credentials.
    - Ability to notify user about certain events.

It seems Canvas apps do not work on mobile platforms. Mobile web apps cant send "App to User" requests/notifications. What would be suitable Facebook application type for our solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook provides a Mobile Web URL in the developer app which they will automatically direct mobile users too when they click on your Canvas URL. So if you had a responsive-ly designed page you could use the same URL for your Canvas URL and your Mobile Web URL.

As for notifications - it depends on your needs - you could use [Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests)

So in answer to your question - you can use more than one application type, and it sounds like you need Canvas and Mobile Web.